How to solve broken pipe error in case of QThread/multiprocessing.Process?
In my pyqt5 main program i instantiate some classes.
Each of this Class instantiate a QThread and a Process.
Also each of this class send data to process via a multiprocessing queue.
When data from process are ready, it send data to QThread via a multiprocessing Pipe and then QThread emits pyqtSignal that are implemented in the parent class (pyqt5).
In many cases when i try to send data to QThread (in most of cases), i am facing this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cpapp\Documents\My Projects\web-radio-studio\src\python+\main-window\page-4\player-list.py", line 3601, in get_player_list
    self.to_emitter.send({"type":"fetch-result","result":self.player_list_items})
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 295, in _send_bytes
    nwritten, err = ov.GetOverlappedResult(True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] The pipe has been ended

This error is oqquered in many pycharm .py executions.
How to avoid it and how can i solve it?
Example code:
main_ui.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 133)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import os
from multiprocessing import freeze_support, Queue
from multiprocessing import Condition, Value, Process, Event
import threading

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread, Qt
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe

from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
import time

class Example_1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()
        
        self.condition = Condition()
        self.frame = Value('q', lock=False)
        self.quit_event = Event()
        self.tr = threading.Thread(target=self.infinite_heartbreat)
        self.tr.start()
        
        self.processes = 30
        self.mother_pipes = []
        self.child_pipes = []
        self.queues = []
        self.emitters = []
        self.child_processes = []
        
        
        for i in range(0,self.processes):
            self.mother_pipes.append(None)
            self.child_pipes.append(None)
            self.mother_pipes[i], self.child_pipes[i] = Pipe()
            self.queues.append(Queue())
            self.emitters.append(Emitter(self.mother_pipes[i]))
            self.emitters[i].signal_1.connect(self.signal_1_handler)
            self.emitters[i].signal_2.connect(self.signal_2_handler)
            self.emitters[i].signal_3.connect(self.signal_3_handler)

            self.emitters[i].start()
            self.child_processes.append(Child_Proc(self.child_pipes[i], self.queues[i],self.condition, self.frame, self.quit_event))
            self.child_processes[i].start()
        
        
        #put some data for test
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()  # set up your QTimer
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.put_data_to_queues)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.start(125)  # set it to timeout in 200 ms
        

        
        self.MainWindow.closeEvent = lambda event: self.closeEvent(event)
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def infinite_heartbreat(self):
        next_beat = time.time()
        while True:
            next_beat += 0.125
            time_to_sleep = next_beat - time.time()
            if time_to_sleep > 0:
                time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
            with self.condition:
                self.frame.value += 1
                self.condition.notify_all()
                if self.quit_event.is_set():
                    print('END')
                    return
        
    def signal_1_handler(self,result):
        #do something with the result in pyqt5 window (display in QLabel for example)
        print(result)
        for process in range(0,self.processes):
            self.queues[process].put({"type":"signal_2","input":result})
    
    def signal_2_handler(self,result):
        #do something with the result in pyqt5 window (display in QLabel for example)
        print(result)
        for process in range(0,self.processes):
            self.queues[process].put({"type":"signal_3","input":result})
                
    def signal_3_handler(self,result):
        #do something with the result in pyqt5 window (display in QLabel for example)
        print(result)
        for process in range(0,self.processes):
            self.queues[process].put({"type":"signal_1","input":result})
        
    def put_data_to_queues(self):
        for process in range(0,self.processes):
            for i in range(1,10):
                self.queues[process].put({"type":"signal_1","input":i})
                self.queues[process].put({"type":"signal_2","input":i})
                self.queues[process].put({"type":"signal_3","input":i})
        
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.quit_event.set()
        self.tr.join()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for i in range(0,self.processes):
            self.emitters[i].signal_1.disconnect()
            self.emitters[i].signal_2.disconnect()
            self.emitters[i].signal_3.disconnect()
            while(self.queues[i].qsize()!=0):
                tmp = self.queues[i].get()
            self.child_processes[i].terminate()
            self.emitters[i].quit()
        
        #print(os.getpid())
        event.accept()
        
class Emitter(QThread):
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_2 = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_3 = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_from_process = from_process
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.data_from_process.poll():
                data = self.data_from_process.recv()
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
            if data["type"]=="signal_1":
                self.signal_1.emit(data["result"])
            elif data["type"]=="signal_2":
                self.signal_2.emit(data["result"])
            elif data["type"]=="signal_3":
                self.signal_3.emit(data["result"])
            elif data["type"]=="stop":
                return None
    
class Child_Proc(Process):

    def __init__(self, to_emitter, from_mother,condition, frame_number, quit_event):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother
        
        self.condition = condition
        self.frame_number = frame_number
        self.quit_event = quit_event

    def run(self):
        current_frame = 0
        while (True):
            with self.condition:
                self.condition.wait_for(lambda: current_frame <= self.frame_number.value)
                if self.quit_event.is_set():
                    self.to_emitter.send({'type':'stop'})
                    return None
            self.one_chunk()
            current_frame += 1
            
    def one_chunk(self):
        qsize = self.data_from_mother.qsize()
        if qsize == 0:
            return None
        data = self.data_from_mother.get()
        if data["type"] == "signal_1":
            result = self.signal_1_method(data["input"])
            self.to_emitter.send({"type":"signal_1","result":result})
        elif data["type"] == "signal_2":
            result = self.signal_2_method(data["input"])
            self.to_emitter.send({"type":"signal_2","result":result})
        elif data["type"] == "signal_3":
            result = self.signal_3_method(data["input"])
            self.to_emitter.send({"type":"signal_3","result":result})
                
    def signal_1_method(self,input_int):
        # some long operation here
        time.sleep(0.125)
        return input_int*10
    
    def signal_2_method(self,input_int):
        # some long operation here
        time.sleep(0.125)
        return input_int*100
        
    def signal_3_method(self,input_int):
        # some long operation here
        time.sleep(0.125)
        return input_int*1000

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        freeze_support()
    program = Example_1()

In this example i cannot reproduce the error.
The cpu usage of this program is: 2,5% (not big)
In the real actual program is ~23%
Anyway AI chatgpt suggestion is to use different Queue for QThread and different Queue for Process, and not Pipe().
Why?
Is this unorthodox?
The original project:

Download project folder from google drive (this is so big due the mp3 assets for db purposes).
Install python 3.10.0 on windows (in my case windows 11 pro).
Install the neccessary modules by running: web-radio-studio/modules-setup/pip-commands.bat
Create the necessary database file by running: python web-radio-studio/db/create-db.py
Create a python folder project in pycharm (community edition) by selecting the web-radio-studio folder
In pycharm edit the run/debug configurations. Edit the python interpretter, and select the run script which is: web-radio-studio/src/python+/main-window/web-radio-studio.py

That's it! Now the project will be ready for run!
Note that the error is not oquered every time i run the program, so be patient with the project.
Thanks in advance

Close vote retracted, question upvoted, thank you -- I don't have an answer offhand without investigating, but everything needed to investigate is here now.

Nice, a put a further example in case of many QThreads, Processes to test if the error is related to many QThreads/Processes instances...

Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details including the Python version.

You can't really ever know "why" a generative AI tool presented a given response to you, unless you can see the internal workings of the tool and all the data it was trained on.
